# users table - user_name vs. nicename

Tags: user-registration

Can someone explain the differences or different uses of the user_name and user_nicename fields in the users table?  They seem to be, and behave the same.

I found a bunch of posts in web searches, but they are relevant only to older version of wp.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The nicename is (usually) just a sanitized version of the username. It's suppose to be 'nice' in the sense that it is the 'nicename' that is used as a slug, for example:

```
www.yoursite.com/author/my-nice-name/
```

will take you to the archive of the author with nicename 'my-nice-name'.

The documentation simply describes it as

> A string that contains a nicer looking name for the user.

Comment: Thanks - what type of characters are allowed during sign-up that would be removed during "sanitization"?

Comment: `sanitize_title` does the sanitizing. According to [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L824) it strips HTML & PHP tags. It seems to replace spaces with '-' somewhere. Note if you provide a nicename in [`wp_insert_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) it doesn't do any sanitizing.

Comment: Got it... makes perfect sense.

Comment: The fact that the documentation says "A string that contains a nicer looking name for the user." is really confusing. You would think that this meant that a "nice" name is one with capitals and spaces, pretty for the user, but apparently, it is exactly the opposite!

Comment: agreed. my brain just commited suicide.